# How is electromagnetism a force and a field and a wave and a photon?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, visible-light

Based on light being a form of EM?

Answer (score 6):

*Electromagnetism* is the name of the *subject* that deals with electric and magnetic fields.

Electric fields exert forces *on* charges (or, if you prefer, charged particles) and magnetic fields can exert forces on moving charges. The fields themselves are not forces.

Oscillating electric and magnetic fields can indeed travel together as an electromagnetic wave, but you can have constant, static fields that are not wave-like.

Electromagnetic wave energy is quantised. The quanta are called *photons*. Electromagnetic waves carry energy and momentum, the relationship being $E=|\mathbf p|c$. It should not be surprising, then, that the same relationship applies to individual photons.

Answer (score 1):

## Physics is just models for reality

These are different models of electromagnetism and different aspects of those models.

Physics is concerned with "models", those are mathematical formulas combined with a prescription how to connect them to measurements.

A model is a good model, if it matches known experimental data and can predict the outcome of future experiments. Of course, a model is only helpful, if there are experiments that can tell whether it is false (falsifiability). If you can't falsify your model, it also can't make any useful predictions (because the predictions are not connected to what happens in the lab).

In reality we know *all* our models to be false – they are just approximations and hold only under certain preconditions.

A simple example is the mathematical pendulum. For small oscillation amplitudes the pendulum's motion is well described by $\phi(t) = \Phi \sin(\omega t + \phi_0)$ – this model of the mathematical pendulum has assumptions, namely that the amplitude is small, but also that on the timescales you consider the drag in the air and friction at the pivot point can be neglected. If those preconditions are not true, we have to use a more complete model of the mathematical pendulum, that includes the effects of larger amplitudes and friction.

The same is true for the electromagnetic field – it is a model for something we see in the lab. Depending on the parameters of the lab setup, different models of the electromagnetic field are required to describe the situation.

Of course, the more general model must include the predictions of the simpler model (although you can derive approximative models from it that are valid in certain parameter spaces, that do *not* contain the original model). If the old model can't explain the verified predictions of the old model, it is already falsified.

## The models of electromagnetism

If you consider a mechanical system, you can just model electromagnetism as the Lorentz force.

This breaks down when the particles in your system get too fast or are far away from each other, so that the finite velocity of effects becomes relevant. Then you have to consider the classical field theory of electromagnetism. Here the field itself is a dynamical object that obeys certain equations (the Maxwell equations). This field carries momentum, influences charges and is in turn influenced by charges, accelerating charges will emit electromagnetic waves.

Electromagnetic waves are excitations of the electromagnetic field that can travel through space on their own. They are solutions of the vacuum Maxwell equations. So being a field and supporting wave solutions is no contradiction at all – it falls naturally out of the field equations.

If we now look at light at low intensities and do "funny things with it", the quantum nature of light becomes obvious. E.g. you can entangle a pair of photons. We can make an experiment where this becomes relevant (e.g. the typical quantum cryptography setup, where two observers measure entangled photons and in turn get correlated results). In this picture we see that the electromagnetic field does not have "continuous excitations" like in the classical field theory, but that only discrete packets of energy can be added or removed from the field (depending on the frequency). These energy packets are called "photons" and are the fundamental excitations of the electromagnetic quantum field.

## How the models relate

It is clear how the field theory includes mechanics – if the velocities and accelerations of the mass points are small and their distances are not too large, then the delay of the force will not be noticeable and emission of em-waves will be strongly suppressed.

You can also show, how classical field theory emerges as the limit of quantum field theory – a so called "coherent state" of photons corresponds to a classical electromagnetic wave.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very very broad answer for a seemingly equally broad question. If you're not looking for linguistic descriptions and elementary explanations, do not bother reading this answer.
In the simplest terms I can think of, it's a force because it causes certain particles to deviate from uniform motion, meaning it changes their velocity. That's one way force is defined. If a body accelerates, then, by definition, a force is acting on it.
It's a field because, in the simplest terms, a field is just a function that has some value over some region in space. If you place a test particle at a given distance from an electron for example, it experiences a certain force/field. If you place it at another point in space, the force/field is different. The value of the field is different at different points in space, just like a usual function.
A wave, in physics, is just a transfer of energy from one point to another. So it's very natural to think of light as a wave, given all the energy you get from the sun. Of course that includes all electromagnetic frequencies, not just light. You can think of a wave as something that describes the propagation of that energy from point to point and over time. So if an electron is moving for example, the electric field it produces changes over time at a given location in space. And, more technically, the field stores or carries energy and momentum with it. So it makes sense to think of them as waves, i.e. as propagations of energy.
The wave description also implies that light exhibits wave properties, like diffraction and interference, which is known experimentally to be true. So that's another way of thinking about it.

The photon description is more technical but it just means that light can also behave like a particle under certain circumstances. That means it has momentum to it as it moves. That's also experimentally known to be true. You would weigh more in the sun than in the dark because the light from the sun exerts pressure on you and that means it's pushing you down with a force, meaning it has momentum. You can also think of it like tiny drops of water in a stream. The stream is like the field and the drops are like the little particles that make up that field. When you throw a small stone in water, tiny droplets would splash out. Those are the excitations of the stream or the field in this case. That's basically one way of thinking about a photon, i.e. an excitation of a field, whatever that means.
This, I would say, is a gross simplification of what those things mean more technically and rigorously. I hope my hand-waving wasn't too far off.